# I can't compile a plugin i downloaded for gkrellm

Tags: command-line, compiling, gtk, gcc, make

When I put in the command `make` the output is

```
/Downloads/gkrellmbgchg2-0.1.11$ make
cc -Wall -fPIC `pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --cflags` -I/usr/local/include   -c -o gkrellmbgchg.o gkrellmbgchg.c
Package gtk+-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk+-2.0' found
In file included from /usr/include/gkrellm2/gkrellm.h:41:0,
                 from gkrellmbgchg.h:5,
                 from gkrellmbgchg.c:30:
/usr/include/gkrellm2/log.h:37:18: fatal error: glib.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'gkrellmbgchg.o' failed
make: *** [gkrellmbgchg.o] Error 1
```

I also tried `make install` and that didn't make a difference. Also I know I'm in the correct directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated by the error message

```
No package 'gtk+-2.0' found
```

you need to install the development headers and libraries for `gtk+-2.0`, either from your favorite package manager or via the command line using

```
sudo apt install libgtk2.0-dev
```